# How to create borders to a data exported to excel from C# code?

Tags: c#, excel, export-to-excel

In using the following code to export the data into excel

```
OleDbDataAdapter insert = new OleDbDataAdapter();
insert.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [" + DTabbleName + "$A3:" + strGet + "] (" + string.Join(",", colNames) + ") values (" + string.Join(",", colParms) + ")", conn);
for (int i = 0; i < DSreturn.Tables[0].Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            OleDbParameter param = new OleDbParameter();
            param.SourceColumn = DSreturn.Tables[0].Columns[i].ColumnName;
            param.ParameterName = DSreturn.Tables[0].Columns[i].ColumnName;
            param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            param.OleDbType = OleDbType.Char;
            param.Size = 255;
            insert.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(param);
        }            
        insert.Update(DSreturn, DSreturn.Tables[0].TableName);
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            conn.Close();
```

How do i add borders to the exported excel only where data is available. Now i know that we can add the borders without any problem when we access the workbook sheet as below

```
sheet.Range["A1:E15"].Borders.LineStyle = LineStyleType.Double;
sheet.Range["A1:E15"].Borders.Color = Color.DeepSkyBlue;
```

But how do we do this when using oledbadapter Update  function

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can add formatting using the OleDbDataAdapter. This is a "data only" connection that allows you to treat the Excel workbook as a data source. A data source does not contain information about formatting.

If you need to generate a formatted excel document then there are lots of questions on that topic here on SO. Like this one for instance: [Create Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp?rq=1)